# Server Error Message: No File Access

Tags: php

I am having an issues but don't know where to solve it. My template works great in xampp but not on the host server. I get this message:

Warning: `file_get_contents()` [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disables in the server configuration in homepage/......./twitter.php.

The error is on line 64.

```
<?php
/*
For use in the "Parse Twitter Feeds" code below
*/
define("SECOND", 1);
define("MINUTE", 60 * SECOND);
define("HOUR", 60 * MINUTE);
define("DAY", 24 * HOUR);
define("MONTH", 30 * DAY);
function relativeTime($time)
{
$delta = time() - $time;
if ($delta < 2 * MINUTE) {
    return "1 min ago";
}
if ($delta < 45 * MINUTE) {
    return floor($delta / MINUTE) . " min ago";
}
if ($delta < 90 * MINUTE) {
    return "1 hour ago";
}
if ($delta < 24 * HOUR) {
    return floor($delta / HOUR) . " hours ago";
}
if ($delta < 48 * HOUR) {
    return "yesterday";
}
if ($delta < 30 * DAY) {
    return floor($delta / DAY) . " days ago";
}
if ($delta < 12 * MONTH) {
    $months = floor($delta / DAY / 30);
    return $months <= 1 ? "1 month ago" : $months . " months ago";
} else {
    $years = floor($delta / DAY / 365);
    return $years <= 1 ? "1 year ago" : $years . " years ago";
}
}


/*
Parse Twitter Feeds

*/
function parse_cache_feed($usernames, $limit, $type) {
$username_for_feed = str_replace(" ", "+OR+from%3A", $usernames);
$feed = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.atom?screen_name=" . $username_for_feed . "&count=" . $limit;
$usernames_for_file = str_replace(" ", "-", $usernames);
$cache_file = dirname(__FILE__).'/cache/' . $usernames_for_file . '-twitter-cache-' . $type;

if (file_exists($cache_file)) { 
    $last = filemtime($cache_file);
    }

$now = time();
$interval = 600; // ten minutes
// check the cache file
if ( !$last || (( $now - $last ) > $interval) ) {
    // cache file doesn't exist, or is old, so refresh it
    $cache_rss = file_get_contents($feed); (this is line 64)
```

Any help on how to give this access on my host server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your server administrator has disabled access to urls for php file functions ([allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) ini setting). Ask them to enable it, or consider other methods, like [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: Im hosting with 1and1.co.uk. Can I make changes myself or I have to call them and they do it?

Comment: sorry, no experience with 1&1. I'd just call them and ask.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `allow_url_fopen` has not been turned `on` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I just created a `php.ini` file and add: `"allow_url_fopen=on"`, save it and uploaded it to my server and wolla...it works. Thanks again to the guys above!